# jqGrid with default search button

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have been trying to make search button a default button so that  it triggers search when enter key is press. some people suggested add savekey, but I tried and no luck, I guess I didnt know where to add that option.
Thanks in advance!

```
 $($gridName).jqGrid('searchGrid', {
        overlay: 0,
        Find: "Search",
        multipleSearch: true,
        multipleGroup: false,
        sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc'],
        caption: "Advanced Search", 
        beforeShowSearch: function () {
         form.keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                  try {$(".ui-icon-search").trigger("click");} catch (e) { } 
                }
            });

            $('#search_grid').width(560);
            $('#search_grid .opsel option[value="OR"]').remove();
            return true;
        }, 
        onReset: function () {
            try { 
                $(".ui-icon-closethick").trigger("click");
            } catch (e) { }
            $($gridName).setGridParam({ datatype: 'local' });
            saveColumnState.call($gridName, $gridName[0].p.remapColumns);
        }
    });
```

Found solution. code has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out answer for my own question. in case someone else run into similar issue. Here is what I did that seems to work

```
 if (e.which == 13) {
 try {$(".ui-icon-search").trigger("click");} catch (e) { } 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting your solution - it's very valuable!. Which part of the grid definition did this go into?

Comment: No problem. I updated code in the original post with the solution.